# NodeJS and MariaDB, wait for query result

Tags: node.js, promise, async-await, mariadb

I have the following code:

```
pool.getConnection()
.then(conn => {
    return conn.query("SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='SquadgoalsDB';")
        .then((rows)=>{
            for(let i=0; i< rows.length;i++){
                tableNames.push(rows[i].table_name)
            }
            tableNames = []
            if(tableNames.length == 0){
                throw new Error("NO_TABLES_FOUND")
            }
            return conn.query("select DISTINCT(column_name) from information_schema.columns WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='SquadgoalsDB'")
        })
        .then((rows)=>{
            for(let i=0; i< rows.length;i++){
                columnNames.push(rows[i].column_name)
            }
            if(columnNames.length == 0){
                throw new Error("NO_COLUMNS_FOUND")
            }
            conn.end()
            console.log("MariaDB connection works")
        })
        .catch((err) =>{
            throw err;
            conn.end()
        })

}).catch(err =>{
    console.log("not connected to mariadb due to error: " + err);
});


module.exports.tableNames = tableNames;  //always empty
module.exports.columnNames = columnNames; // always empty
```

I want to search for all table and column names inside my database. After this I have some more server starting stuff going on and i want to export the two arrays shown above, but they are always empty becauses we don't wait for the queries? How can I wait (probably with async/await) for the above code to finish and after that continue with the exports and other stuff?

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do it like that: **await**  should wait for the whole promise chain to finish and it should recieve an object representing a resolved or rejected promise.
But keep in mind that the export is an **async** operation aswell so it might happen before the function is finished.

The best way to work with an ansync system is to use callback. You need to export a callback assignation method to get the callback, and call it on the async execution.

```
module.exports = pool.getConnection()
    .then( async (conn) => {
       return await conn.query("SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='SquadgoalsDB';")
            .then((rows)=>{
                for(let i=0; i< rows.length;i++){
                    tableNames.push(rows[i].table_name)
                }
                tableNames = []
                if(tableNames.length == 0){
                    throw new Error("NO_TABLES_FOUND")
                }
                return conn.query("select DISTINCT(column_name) from information_schema.columns WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='SquadgoalsDB'")
            })
            .then((rows)=>{
                for(let i=0; i< rows.length;i++){
                    columnNames.push(rows[i].column_name)
                }
                if(columnNames.length == 0){
                    throw new Error("NO_COLUMNS_FOUND")
                }
                conn.end()
                console.log("MariaDB connection works")
            })
            .catch((err) =>{
                throw err;
                conn.end()
            })

    }).catch(err =>{
        console.log("not connected to mariadb due to error: " + err);
    });
```

And in another file you can do:

```
(async function(){

  let foo = await require("./codeabove");
  console.log(foo);
})();
```